# How to make Spyder wait until matplotlib plot has been constructed

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

Coming from a R background I am now moving on to Python and would like to learn Spyder 4 as a next tool alongside RStudio for data analysis. I am running into a problem however trying to learn matplotlib.

Having this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,4,3,3,2,4,5,6]
y = [5,5,6,7,8,3,4,5,6,7,8,6,5,4,3,2]

plt.xlabel('x-as')
plt.ylabel('y-as')
plt.title('My title')
plt.legend()
plt.scatter(x, y, label = 'test')
plt.show()
```

This will not wait for the call to `plt.show()`, but instead plot a graph for each of the calls to a matplotlib functions, in the plot viewer section of the IDE.

How would I make Spyder 4 wait untill I actually want it to draw the graph?

Answer (score 0):

You want to put `fig = plt.figure()` before the rest of the plotting lines. Also, you want to put `plt.legend()` after the scatter function so that the label shows.